# Dynamic Variable Array Type in Custom Object

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to create a custom object from a server response that has several consistent fields as well as an array of objects. Let's call it a `DynamicResponse`. For any individual `DynamicResponse`, the objects in that array will be the same type of some custom object, but different `DynamicResponse` objects will have different types of custom objects. Example of what I'm trying to explain below.

Is there a way to positively type the array within `DynamicResponse` when declaring a `DynamicResponse` object? Much like how we create an array object and define the type of objects in that array, I want to create a `DynamicResponse` object and define the type of objects in the custom variable of that object. Right now I have the array typed as `[Any]` and then have to cast it depending on which endpoint is being used. Similar to how Objective-C does something like `Array<Person>` I would love to be able to create a `DynamicResponse<Person>` to indicate that the custom array within the `DynamicResponse` will be of `Person` type. Is there a way to do this?

---

Example

Response A:

```
{
  page: 1,
  count: 26,
  objects: [
    {
      name: "bob",
      occupation: "builder"
    },
    {
      name: "walt",
      occupation: "welder"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Response B:

```
{
  page: 2,
  count: 99,
  objects: [
    {
      location: "Earth",
      inhabitants: 8000000000
    },
    {
      location: "Mars",
      inhabitants: 0
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

So the first `DynamicResponse` is

```
page: Int
count: Int
objects: [Person]
```

and my second `DynamicResponse` is

```
page: Int
count: Int
objects: [StellarObject]
```

All fields stay consistent except for the object type in the array of custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

Just make the type of the array a type parameter constrained to `Codable`:

```
struct DynamicResponse<Item: Codable>: Codable {
    let page: Int
    let count: Int
    let objects: [Item]
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
// if you expect to get a person response
let personResponse = try decoder.decode(DynamicResponse<Person>.self, from: data)
// if you expect to get a stellar object response
let stellarObjectResponse = try decoder.decode(DynamicResponse<StellarObject>.self, from: data)
```